# Detach and Append in Internet Explorer won't work

Tags: jquery, append, detach

Using detach followed by append won't work in Internet Explorer.
Does anyone know why?

I have this hidden div that that pops out in footer using jQuery and it works on every browser except on Internet Explorer (I've tried it on versions 9 and 11).

jQuery

```
movefooter = $('.hidden-div').detach();
$('#footer').append(movefooter);
$('.hidden-div').css("display", "initial");
```

Comment: Which version of IE are you trying to support?

Comment: I edited: I tried versions 9 and 11

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sss4geLr/1/  Works fine for me in IE 11